# Using exim4 as smarthost with multiple recipient servers

Tags: exim, smarthost

I've two mail server, one running exim4 as smarthost. atm it delivers all mails to the second server (with the mailboxes). Now I want the smarthost to send all message also to a new server for testing.

I tried it with:
route_list = domain ip1:ip2

but with this conf exim only sends the mails to ip2 if ip1 is down.
Is there a possibility to send all mails to both?

Comment: nobody knows an answer? :(

Answer (score 0):

You should consider modifying your current smarthost configuration to have 2 smarthost routers, one for each server you want to route to. The **unseen** router option can then be used on the first router causing the following router to process the same address. More information is available within the Exim documentation:

[Routing in Exim](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch03.html#SECTrunindrou)